Run program on incoming call w/ SIP (callmonitor) on Linux
Friends,
I'd like to run a custom program whenever a SIP call is received, similar to common call monitoring UIs. I do not need any (G)UI for this. I imaginge something like:
/usr/bin/the-imaginary-monitoringing-program --siplogin ... --execute "mycustomprogramm %callerid%"
(Additional info: I do not want to answer the call)
Any hints?
